# TypeORM - return the same instance of entity while requesting relation in find()

Tags: typescript, sqlite, typeorm

Given I have the case when I store in one table currencies and in the second one orders.
Orders usually have the same currencies and now the typeorm creates an instance of entity for each row.
My question is: provided I have the situation listed in the code block below. Is it possible to get the same instance of the currency entity when it is in the relation and is actually the same object taken from the same table?

```js
import { Column, DataSource, Entity, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
class Currency {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  code: string;
}

@Entity()
class Order {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Currency)
  currency: Currency;
}

(async () => {
  const connection = await new DataSource({
    type: 'sqlite',
    database: ':memory:',
    entities: [Order, Currency],
    synchronize: true
  }).initialize();

  const orderRepository = connection.getRepository(Order);
  const currencyRepository = connection.getRepository(Currency);

  const USD = currencyRepository.create({ code: 'USD' });
  await currencyRepository.save(USD);

  await orderRepository.save(orderRepository.create({ currency: USD }));
  await orderRepository.save(orderRepository.create({ currency: USD }));

  const [order1, order2] = await orderRepository.find({ relations: { currency: true } });
  console.assert(order1.currency === order2.currency, 'Need them strictly equal');//out: 'Need them strictly equal'
  console.assert(order1.currency.id === order2.currency.id, 'Ids are not the same'); //out: 
})();
```

what I checked so far:
well, that might be potentially affected place
https://github.com/spamshaker/typeorm/blob/6e888dd0a13110f386ed538161740ae059491b91/src/query-builder/transformer/RawSqlResultsToEntityTransformer.ts#L300
but... the question is if there is a way to override this implementation or use some existing solution before applying "brutal" patch :)